# How to execute a function when page has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript

I need to execute some JavaScript code when the page has fully loaded. This includes things like images.

I know you can check if the DOM is ready, but I don’t know if this is the same as when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: So, how do you check if the DOM is ready?

Comment: saw this working if java scripts are loading async https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618464/how-to-wait-for-another-js-to-load-to-proceed-operation

Answer (score 643, accepted):

That's called `load`. It came waaaaay before DOM ready was around, and DOM ready was actually created for the exact reason that `load` waited on images.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  alert("It's loaded!")
})
```

Comment: so, just to clarify (if I may), comparing to DOM ready, `window.onload` is called when *every* page component/resourse (i.e. *including *images). Am I right?

Comment: @BreakPhreak: yes :) `onload` waits for all resources that are part of the document. This excludes, of course, requests created dynamically that are not part of the document itself, e.g., an AJAX request.

Comment: script is not loaded fully

Comment: What if my script may be dynamically loaded and "load" event occurred before I added my handler?

Comment: Did anybody faced issue with this approach in IE ? I am facing issues with IE11

Comment: @Matchu - thanks for this amazing answer, how include  the AJAX request in the scope of the observer ?

Comment: Doesn't work. At least on I-phone/IOS (as of IOS 12, both chrome and safari), putting this in the initial page in a stand alone <script> block will cause the alert long before the IOS provided progress bar completes. Putting it in a function specifically tied to the <body onload="function()" makes it trigger a little closer to completion, but is still not happening when the browser actually finishes. At least that's what my tests show on these mobile browsers as of 9/2020

Comment: @Randy Maybe it's the bug [geocar mentions below?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033557/4751990)

Comment: Is there a way to take advantage of the await async syntax? Using multiple nested callbacks would be ugly...

Answer (score 40):

For completeness sake, you might also want to bind it to DOMContentLoaded, which is now widely supported

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  // your code here
});
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: This answer is precisely opposite of what was asked in the question.

Comment: Indeed the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered when all DOM contents have been loaded, before it has loaded all its dependencies. Since users in the thread of answers referenced `$.ready` I thought it made a good contribution. 
Btw. I'd use the `addEventListener`-method also for the `load` event though, as it allows you to have multiple callbacks: `window.addEventListener("load", function(event){  // your code here });`

Comment: my DOMContentLoaded event is not fired

Comment: @Dee it should, it is quite an old event supported by all major browsers for years; perhaps you have some slow loading resources on your page. If you need help sorting out your particular problem, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 35):

Usually you can use `window.onload`, but you may notice that recent browsers don't fire `window.onload` when you use the back/forward history buttons.

Some people [suggest](http://www.thomasfrank.se/when_onload_fails.html) weird contortions to work around this problem, but really if you just make a `window.onunload` handler (even one that doesn't do anything), this caching behavior will be disabled in *all* browsers. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) documents this "feature" pretty well, but for some reason there are still people using `setInterval` and other weird hacks.

Some versions of Opera have a bug that can be worked around by adding the following somewhere in your page:

```
<script>history.navigationMode = 'compatible';</script>
```

If you're just trying to get a javascript function called once per-view (and not necessarily after the DOM is finished loading), you can do something like this:

```
<img src="javascript:location.href='javascript:yourFunction();';">
```

For example, I use this trick to preload a very large file into the cache on a loading screen:

```
<img src="bigfile"
onload="this.location.href='javascript:location.href=\'javascript:doredir();\';';doredir();">
```

Comment: Can anyone clarify how *this trick* works? Too complicated for me, doh..

Answer (score 35):

Try this code

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    initApplication();
  }
}
```

visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.readyState for more details

Comment: Yeah, this is helpful. Thanks a lot~

Comment: `"interactive"` is not fully loaded.  `"complete"` is fully loaded

Comment: At last! Thanks a million, Jacob. All the numerous methods listed here having failed (at best, a radiobutton would be updated, and a resulting calculation could be done, but the button would not appear pressed), your method does the trick.

Comment: The only solution that actually worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

**Try this it Only Run After Entire Page Has Loaded**

By Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    // code goes here
};
```

By Jquery

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

Comment: `$(window)` makes me think this would be jquery -- right? Or am I getting some javascript syntax confused? (I'm new to JS).

Comment: why not simply use `$(document).ready();` when jQuery is available?

Comment: yours is the document (more or less just the parsed HTML), the other ("load") is _everything_ including images and styles. Depends on what you need.

Answer (score 10):

Javascript using the `onLoad()` event, will wait for the page to be loaded before executing.

```
<body onload="somecode();" >
```

If you're using the jQuery framework's document ready function the code will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // jQuery code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 9):

the window.onload event will fire when everything is loaded, including images etc.

You would want to check the DOM ready status if you wanted your js code to execute as early as possible, but you still need to access DOM elements.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload), as the docs indicate that it's not fired until both the DOM is ready and ALL of the other assets in the page (images, etc.) are loaded.

Comment: Ah brilliant. Well ive done this. The last image on the page is this:

<img src="imdbupdate.php?update=ajax" style="display:hidden" onload="window.location = 'movies.php?do=admincp'" />

However it doesn't readirect me

Comment: ...what? You want to redirect once an image loads?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want that, but the reason it doesn't redirect may be that it's display:hidden, and thus the browser doesn't bother to load it since it will not be shown.

Comment: maybe it's just a hidden image that does something important on the server, such as tracking a hit or doing something in the DB?

Comment: I can get that, but to have it redirect after doesn't make sense to me. Why have the page at all if you don't want the user to spend time on it? And if the goal is to redirect on load, why not just use a window.onload event, since it's a cleaner implementation overall?

Answer (score 8):

In modern browsers with modern javascript (>= 2015) you can add `type="module"` to your script tag, and everything inside that script will execute after whole page loads. e.g:

```html
<script type="module">
  alert("runs after") // Whole page loads before this line execute
</script>
<script>
  alert("runs before")
</script>
```

also older browsers will understand `nomodule` attribute. Something like this:

```html
<script nomodule>
  alert("tuns after")
</script>
```

For more information you can visit [javascript.info](http://javascript.info/modules-intro).

Answer (score 3):

Completing the answers from @Matchu and @abSiddique.

This:

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
});
```

Is the same as this but using the `onload` event handler property:

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
};
```

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Live example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event#live_example

Answer (score 2):

And here's a way to do it with [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org/):

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function(event) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> The **onload** property of the GlobalEventHandlers mixin is an event
>   handler for the load event of a **Window, XMLHttpRequest,  element,
>   etc.,** which fires when the resource has loaded.

So basically javascript already has onload method on window which get executed which page fully loaded including images...

You can do something:

```
var spinner = true;

window.onload = function() {
  //whatever you like to do now, for example hide the spinner in this case
  spinner = false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This calls `yourFunction()` after the page has loaded, whether or not the document has already loaded by the time this code is executed

```js
if (document.readyState === 'complete') yourFunction();
else window.addEventListener('load', () => yourFunction());
```

See https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded for thorough teaching about stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

### If you need to use many `onload` use `$(window).load` instead (jQuery):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //code
});
```

Answer (score -5):

**2019 update:** This is was the answer that worked for me. As I needed multiple ajax requests to fire and return data first to count the list items.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
       alert("Everything is ready now!");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything related with the question. This code is related to an Ajax request.