# How to start a JS code when the whole page has loaded including images (real on complete)

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I want to execute a script after the whole page has loaded, when it's complete.

The current way is:

```
window.onload=document.getElementById('loaded').value=1;
```

Which is not good, as some images are still in load, and the page has not completed loading truly. What I am doing wrong?

Certainly doesn't work for me in Chrome and Firefox. The thing is I launch a code after, that returns status 204, and this blocks future loads. But it seams this 204 status is returned way before the page has finished loading. So I need to execute my code after the page has truly loaded.

**EDIT**

setup a page, that does framebreaking

```
<iframe id="myframe" height=1 width=1></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload=document.getElementById('myframe').src='http://link to a frame braker page';
</script>
```

when you put the above code to a page, it loads the iframe before the page is fully loaded. Simply put an alert in the iframe page, and try out on a slower server where your parent page contains large images etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> window.onload=document.getElementById('loaded').value=1;

You've forgotten to turn that into a function. What you're saying is:

```
document.getElementById('loaded').value= 1;
window.onload= 1;
```

Obviously that's not very effective as a load detector. What you meant was probably:

```
window.onload= function() {
    document.getElementById('loaded').value= '1';
};
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation, and for actually solving the OP's problem!

Answer (score 4):

The `window.onload` event should wait for images to load before it is fired:

> The load event fires at the end of the
>   document loading process. At this
>   point, all of the objects in the
>   document are in the DOM, and **all the
>   images and sub-frames have finished
>   loading.**
>
> Source: [Mozilla Dev Center: window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)

You may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for further reading:

- [Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

---

**UPDATE:**

The reason why your implementation is not working has identified by [bobince in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621435/how-to-start-a-js-code-when-the-whole-page-has-loaded-including-images-real-on-c/2621812#2621812). The solution is to use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('loaded').value = '1';
};
```

Comment: Well certainly doesn't work for me in Chrome and Firefox. The thing is I launch a code after that returns status 204, and this blocks future loads. But it seams this 204 status is returned way before the page has finished loading. So I need to execute my code after the page has truly loaded.

Comment: @Pentium10: That's interesting. Do you think you can post a very short code example that reproduces this problem?

Answer (score -1):

If you can use Jquery, have a look to [FrameReady](http://ideamill.synaptrixgroup.com/?page_id=18) plugin.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe) SO question. for further information

Comment: I was sure OP was talking about Iframe; messed up with another question probably :).