# Loading Google Maps API after the page is displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My landing page contains a big google maps portion, which slows down the loading time. I am trying to do the following:

1. Load the static elements first so the page loads fast initially.
2. Display a loading notification in the map placeholder so that the user knows that the map is coming up
3. Load and display the map

I have done this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  map_initialize();
}
```

The `map_initialize()` function loads the map into its container div. However, this still will not display the static elements fist. The page will wait until the `map_initialize()` is finished, then load the static elements at the same time as the map.

Comment: There's a shorthand for that function, you could write: $(function() { map_initialize(); } );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `window.onload` event will wait for the images, and any other resource on the document, to load before it gets fired:

> The load event fires at the end of the
>   document loading process. At this
>   point, all of the objects in the
>   document are in the DOM, and **all the
>   images and sub-frames have finished
>   loading.**
>
> Source: [Mozilla Dev Center: window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)

You may also want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for further reading:

- [Execute JavaScript When Page Has Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Therefore all you need to do is to set the `window.onload` event handler as follows:

```
window.onload = map_initialize;
```

Comment: Might I say that the latest version off google maps provides a callback function `https://maps.google...?...&callback=initMap&libraries=..."

Answer (score 2):

I worked on this functionality and faced this issue.Solution is ..

```
function initMap() {
  --google map code--
}

$(document).ready(function () {
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery you could do:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => { 
    map_initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').load(function() {
  map_initialize();
});
```

[edit] I just found this from the user comments in the jQuery documentation :
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/#comment-43474051

Answer (score 0):

If you use the onLoad event the static elements should load before your map. The `ready` method in JQuery will run before everything is loaded; it runs as soon as `document` is ready.