# Google maps not display entire map on the div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a div with a google map inside but the map is not showing entirely.. just shows a part of the map and the other it's all grey and if i move the map with the cursor, the maps visual part moves fine but the size changes but not taking the entire div size.

This is the div and a snapshot:

```
<div style="height: 275px; width: 715px;" id="map_display"></div>
```

[image: This is a snapshot]

Comment: This might be refresh problem. try to reinitialize the map once page loaded. it will help. or show your code

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger a resize event in Google maps like

```
google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');
```

After initializing the Google maps

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702362/loading-google-maps-api-after-the-page-is-displayed) may be of use to you, the problem is likely that the map has been loaded prior to the sizing of the div (is it perhaps dynamically sized?).

Loading the map after the rest of the page elements should help.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86VVh/)

```
function InitializeMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_display"), myOptions);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitializeMap();
});
```