# Open popup from Controller in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, popup, alert

I'm creating my first sample Rails application. I have used rufus-scheduler in my application and call controller's action after every 10 sec. My code as follows:

In config/initializers I've created task_scheduler.rb and it contains:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.every("10s") do
  MyTaskController.doSomething
end
```

I also created a controller named MyTaskController and code is:

```
 class MyTaskController < ApplicationController
  def self.doSomething
    puts "some task"
  end
end
```

**It works perfectly, but I want to show a popup alert instead of using puts function. Is it possible in rails to call a javascript alert or javascript:window.open from controller (my doSomething action)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can render a view which has javascript code in it that contains javascript alert or javascript:window.open

Similar question was brought up:
[Rails 3: How to send Javascript code from Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472227/rails-3-how-to-send-javascript-code-from-controller)

Answer (score -1):

All you need is some JavaScript library such as jQuery, Lightbox, etc. to do that