# Detect if page has finished loading

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect when a page has finished loading ie all its content, javascript and assets like css and images?

so like:

```
if(PAGE HAS FINISHED LOADING)
{
// do something amazing
}
```

and also additionally if the page has been loading for more than 1 min then do something else such as:

```
if(PAGE HAS BEEN LOADING FOR 1 MIN)
{
// do something else amazing
}
```

I've seen websites like Apple's MobileMe do similar checks but haven't been able to figure it out in their huge code libraries.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT: This is essentially what I want to do:

```
// hide content
$("#hide").hide();

// hide loading
$("#loading").hide();

// fade in loading animation
setTimeout($('#loading').fadeIn(), 200);

jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $("#hide").fadeIn();

  $("#loading").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    clearInterval(loadingAnim);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#error").fadeIn();
  }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `window.onload` (or `$(window).load()`) wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi @Cameron. Which code works to hide the loader after the page has finished loading?

Comment: @TonyNg See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083693/detect-if-page-has-finished-loading/45008459#45008459

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function () {
    alert('page is loaded');

    setTimeout(function () {
        alert('page is loaded and 1 minute has passed');   
    }, 60000);

});
```

Or http://jsfiddle.net/tangibleJ/fLLrs/1/

See also http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ for an explanation on the jQuery(window).load.

**Update**

A detailed explanation on how javascript loading works and the two events *DOMContentLoaded* and *OnLoad* can be found on [this page](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/).

**DOMContentLoaded**: When the **DOM is ready** to be manipulated. jQuery's way of capturing this event is with `jQuery(document).ready(function () {});`.

**OnLoad**: When the **DOM is ready and all assets** - this includes **images, iframe, fonts, etc** - have been loaded and the spinning wheel / hour class disappear. jQuery's way of capturing this event is the above mentioned `jQuery(window).load`.

Comment: If you look at my OP I have amended it so that it shows what my aims are. So essentially I want to show the page after all assets have loaded and fade out a loader and fade in the content. Would my code work correctly? Cheers

Comment: Your code looks alright but I'd have to see it in action to be sure.

Comment: @Jimmer Yes:  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load):  _"The load event is fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading."_

Comment: Please note that `jQuery.load()` was deprecated since jQuery/1.8 and removed in jQuery/3. Current syntax is `jQuery(window).on("load", function(){/*...*/});`.

Answer (score 65):

***there are two ways to do this in jquery depending what you are looking for..***

**using jquery you can do**

- //this will wait for the text assets to be loaded before calling this
  (the dom.. css.. js)

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){...});
  ```
- //this will wait for all the images and text assets to finish loading
  before executing

  ```
  $(window).load(function(){...});
  ```

Comment: In this method, how can you tell if the page has been loading for several minutes but is not yet complete?

Comment: this can be accomplished with a setTimeout(function(){ !loaded && foo();},20000);

and set loaded  to true in the doc ready or window load

Comment: for jquery 3.0 use   $(window).on("load", function (e) { });

Answer (score 17):

That's called onload. DOM ready was actually created for the exact reason that onload waited on images. ( Answer taken from [Matchu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107415/matchu) on a simmilar question a while ago. )

```
window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!") }
```

onload waits for all resources that are part of the document.

Link to a question where he explained it all:

[Click me, you know you want to!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: The problem with onload is that if I do `window.onload = function(){...}` when the page is already loaded nothing happens. Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest way would be

```
var items = $('img, style, ...'), itemslen = items.length;

items.bind('load', function(){ 
    itemslen--;
    if (!itemlen) // Do stuff here
});
```

EDIT, to be a little crazy:

```
var items = $('a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, area, audio, b, base, ' + 
    'basefont, bdo, bgsound, big, body, blockquote, br, button, canvas, ' + 
    'caption, center, cite, code, col, colgroup, comment, custom, dd, del, ' +
    'dfn, dir, div, dl, document, dt, em, embed, fieldset, font, form, frame, ' +
    'frameset, head, hn, hr, html, i, iframe, img, input, ins, isindex, kbd, ' +
    'label, legend, li, link, listing, map, marquee, media, menu, meta, ' +
    'nextid, nobr, noframes, noscript, object, ol, optgroup, option, p, ' +
    'param, plaintext, pre, q, rt, ruby, s, samp, script, select, small, ' + 
    'source, span, strike, strong, style, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, ' + 
    'textarea, tfoot, th, thead, title, tr, tt, u, ul, var, wbr, video, ' + 
    'window, xmp'), itemslen = items.length;

items.bind('load', function(){ 
    itemslen--;
    if (!itemlen) // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: I kind of like this idea HOWEVER itemslen never seems to count down to 0.

Comment: BEWARE OF THIS METHOD - It assumes all the listed elements have a 'load' event, which many of them in the example do not.

Answer (score 10):

Another option you can check the [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) like,

```
var chkReadyState = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        // clear the interval
        clearInterval(chkReadyState);
        // finally your page is loaded.
    }
}, 100);
```

From the documentation of readyState Page the summary of complete state is

> Returns "loading" while the document is loading, "interactive" once it
>   is finished parsing but still loading sub-resources, and "complete"
>   once it has loaded.

Comment: I've been having issues with cached images, and this seems to be the better code for that in performance... Wondering about practice? Seems to be better than the jQuery `$(window).on("load" function () {//dostuff})`...?

Answer (score 6):

FYI of people that have asked in the comments, this is what I actually used in projects:

```
function onLoad(loading, loaded) {
    if(document.readyState === 'complete'){
        return loaded();
    }
    loading();
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', loaded);
    }
};

onLoad(function(){
   console.log('I am waiting for the page to be loaded');
},
function(){
    console.log('The page is loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to have the page be blank, containing a small amount of javascript. Use the script to make an AJAX call to get the actual page content, and have the success function write the result over the current document. In the timeout function you can "do something else amazing"

Approximate pseudocode:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax
      url of actual page
      success:do something amazing
      timeout: do something else
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's the first way that came to mind when I asked myself "How can a page tell if a request for it times out?"

Comment: well it will not tell you if the images have finished loading.. rather it will only say if the raw markup has been loaded

Comment: Hm. Leads me to an interesting question. If you just did $(document).html(response), and response contained a document.ready or a window.load, would that execute once the document is written? Or would the browser see the page as already loaded and not call them on the content change?

Comment: i think it will call it a second time but not 100% ... try it out

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
$("document").ready( function() {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This will run when the DOM is ready, but that can be before things like images have finished loading.

Answer (score 2):

Without jquery or anything like that beacuse why not ?

```
var loaded=0;
var loaded1min=0;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   loaded=1;
    setTimeout(function () {
      loaded1min=1;
    }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: This is correct, but slightly different from what `jquery` performs.  `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered only after external content is loaded (notably images, which can take a long time in certain conditions).  `jquery` performs `.ready()` using browser specific events, which (on most browsers) happen before external content is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pageLoaded=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
   pageLoaded=1;
});
```

Using jquery: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/