# Execute contents inside <script> after loading the page in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my htmlpage there is an script tag

Something like this

```
<script id="loadmenu"></script>
```

The "src" attribute for the above script element depends on the enviornment in which the web application is hosted.

So I wrote something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#loadmenu").attr("src",SRConfig.WESHost + "/webapp/" + SRConfig.WESApp+ "/servlet/WPSNav?mod=iwswps&idkey=displayhome");
});
```

The script is being loaded fine from the specified source. But the script is loaded only after the document is being parsed and loaded in the browser.
Since I am using $(document).ready().

As the document is finished parsing, the script is not getting executed after being loaded. Is there any way I can execute the `specific <script> tag`
 after the
web page is being parsed and loaded in browser?

Comment: Are you sure the script is loaded? when you change the "src" of the script tag, the browser will not download the script file. Check out my answer below

Comment: yeah...after loading it will be like<script id.....>myMethod()</script>. But myMethod() is not executed, cos the script is loaded sfter the page is parsed.

Comment: Use built-in browser's network capture feature to see if the script is loaded or not. I checked and did not see it loaded. It's only loaded when we insert script tags.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you jquery selector is not correct. It should be

```
$("#loadmenu").attr("src",SRConfig.WESHost + "/webapp/" + SRConfig.WESApp+ "/servlet/WPSNav?mod=iwswps&idkey=displayhome");
```

Comment: As Live java said "The script is being loaded fine from the specified source", I'm guessing this is a copy/paste error, and `loadmenu` is defined in his/her code.

Comment: come on,its a copy paste error!I have debugged using firebug, the script is getting loaded

Comment: @Dropout: this does not work. The OP has updated the question.

Comment: @KhanhTO thanks for the info, but this was not my answer.. I was just pointing out that the aforementioned user had a good point regarding jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Insert script tag instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scriptTag = $("<script/>");
    scriptTag.attr("src",SRConfig.WESHost + "/webapp/" + SRConfig.WESApp+ "/servlet/WPSNav?mod=iwswps&idkey=displayhome");
    $("head").append(scriptTag);
});
```

or use a similar code of [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted/).

```
(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "Your URL";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'loadmenu'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Detect if page has finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083693/detect-if-page-has-finished-loading) if it helps you.

Basically you can use .load function with window to see if it's fully loaded and trigger your script after that.

Documentation:

> http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: how to trigger the script?

Comment: Please read http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ it's not that long.. You can "hook" the .load function to images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are modifying the `src` attribute in javascript ?

If the script path to load is determined by the hosted web application, I'm guessing you could simply do something like:

```
<script id="loadmenu" src="${SRConfig.WESHost}/webapp/${SRConfig.WESApp}/servlet/WPSNav?mod=iwswps&idkey=displayhome"></script>
```

The `${}` being replaced in your html template by your server side app.

I'm not familiar with the technology behind theses `SRConfig.*` so I could be totally wrong.