# Jquery do another action after load() complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#container').load(h);
$('#container').fadeIn();
```

I have a button click can load another file into it.

My problem is jquery run fadeIn while page is still loading.

Is any way to set fadeIn after the page load is finish?

Comment: This was already answered in different threads, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7083802/432681.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use callback function that is executed when the request completes.

```
$('#container').load(h,function(){
   $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

[.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)