# How to get loading request of browser

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

when developing web automatic testing script, it's hard to determinate when to start the next step, especially after the refreshing or searching. by using firebug, i can get the background requesting. so i wanna if there's anyway to get the loading background request of browser using JavaScript?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083693/detect-if-page-has-finished-loading