# How to autorefresh if page failed to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I had come up with these solution: 
**My Solution / Expectation:**
Put a setTimeout(). So if the page will still not load, in 5sec, I will reload(auto) the page. 
See code:

```
var time;
window.onload = function(){
    time = setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(); }, 5000);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    clearTimeout(time);
});
```

**My Problem** with this solution, is that the page will still reload even if the page has already loaded.

I want to cancel the setTimeout if the page has already loaded, but the code above does not working as expected.

Someone could help me, I really needing this to my thesis. Please help. Thanks in adv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if page has finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083693/detect-if-page-has-finished-loading)

Comment: have you tried document.readyState === 'complete' condition?

Comment: Please note that on mobile it might take longer to load the page, so you will end up with a reload loop.

Comment: @Joshua first I am mam :P and second i have posted my answer mark it correct as it  helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help..as the document itself have readyState variable

```
var time;
window.onload = function() {
    time = setTimeout(function() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            clearTimeout(time);
        } else {
            document.location.reload();
        }

    }, 5000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the jQuery, use `document.readyState` like so:

```
var time;
window.onload = function(){
    time = setTimeout(function(){
        document.location.reload(); 
    }, 5000);
};

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        clearTimeout(time);
    }
}
```