# How do I make sure the HTML content is rendered before `alert` pops up when calling from a setInterval callback?

Tags: javascript, alert, setinterval

Update:

Please take a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/w85kphz6/).

I don't think it has anything to do with `window.load` stuff. It looks like a `setInterval` and `alert` issue. I want to find a best number with a fixed reason, not just some number by luck.

```js
$('body').text('5');
alert('ok1');



$('body').text('6');
setTimeout(function(){
alert('ok2');

},0)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I make sure the HTML page is rendered before `alert` pops up?

Comment: Put it in a $(document).ready function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if page has finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083693/detect-if-page-has-finished-loading)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside a relevant event listener, either `DOMContentLoaded` or `load`:

- [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) – means that the browser fully loaded HTML, and the DOM tree is built, but external resources like pictures  and stylesheets may be not yet loaded
- [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) – not only HTML is loaded, but also all the external resources (images, styles, etc.)

For the `load` (more general) event, your listener would look like that:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  alert('ok1');
  // rest of your code
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w85kphz6/ Would you please take a look at this? By setting `TIMEOUT_MS` to different numbers, like 0, 5, 10 or 20, the alert box would do less or none effect on blocking the HTML refreshing. I am wondering, how do I determine a perfect number to `TIMEOUT_MS`. I think it should be something fixed not by luck.

Comment: @AGamePlayer what do you mean by "blocking the HTML refreshing". This will run after all HTML on the site has been rendered.

Comment: Would you please take a look at this jsfiddle, imo, when the alert pops out, the number on the button should always be 5. But in the real situation, it's not.