# How can I make jQuery and the Animate.css library detect when a page is fully loaded?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery and the Animate.css library to animate the text on my landing page. How can I detect when the page has finished loading so that I can call a function to animate the landing page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if page has finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083693/detect-if-page-has-finished-loading)

Comment: Checkout the loading entrance of this web page and understand what i wanted to achieve....(http://obys.agency)

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

More here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/