# what is the best way to make sure javascript is running when page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to run my javascript in my asp.net webform page but I am not sure it runs properly because all the elements are not loaded yet. How can I make sure my script is at the very bottom of the page with using jquery? So it can run when the page is loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: Do you mean "with jQuery" or "without using jQuery"? If you don't want to use jQuery (and there really is no need to use it just for this) then Raynos has your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure JavaScript, you can use

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Page loaded
};
```

Or you can use jQuery's `ready` function:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    // Dom loaded
} );
```

Note: jQuery's ready function fires when the DOM has loaded (unless the browser does not support a dom-ready method), not when the whole page has loaded (images, scripts, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Even though everyone says use `$(document).ready` it's kind of an anti-pattern.

What you really want to do is put any scripts you want to load at the end of the body

```
<html>
 <head> ... </head>
 <body>
  ...
  <script src="..." ></script>
</html>
```

As long as your scripts are at the end of all your other HTML content the javascript will only fire when the content above it has loaded.

Comment: +1. Fool proof, future proof, backward compatible and independent of any library.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  // page is loaded
});
```

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you want to attach to the ready event. This gets fired when all DOM elements have been loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // jQuery Code here

});
```

Shorthand version:

```
$(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Using this method, I usually put my jQuery in an external file, or in the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code inside the document ready block as suggested in the JQuery documentation.
This way it will be loaded when all the scripts will be loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to make sure javascript is running when page is fully loaded?

If you mean "fully loaded" literally, i.e., *all* images and other resources downloaded, then you have to use an `onload` handler, e.g.:

```
window.onload = function() {
   // Everything has loaded, so put your code here
};
```

If you mean "after all of the HTML has been parsed and all elements are accessible from script", at which point images may still be downloading, then you can either put your script at the bottom of the source HTML or use a document.ready handler. Or both. Refer to any of the other answers for details.