# HTML Background Image OnLoad

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML page with a little JavaScript in it.  The JavaScript launches onLoad in the body.  The body also has a background image.  The JavaScript launches before the background image is loaded.  Is there a way to have the body onLoad wait for the body background image to load?

```
<body background="http://xxx.com/xxx.jpeg" id="myBody" onload="pageLoaded()">
```

Comment: Use window.onload in place of body.onload, as mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make sure a script launches after all the images have been loaded, then use

```
$(window).load(function() {
//.......................
});
```

This event, will only fire once all the scripts, css, js, images have been load, unlike `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
     //your code here
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     //your code here
 });
```

But i don't think whether it will consider background image loading. A more efficient way will be to use this jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

You can make the jQuery function call like :

```
jQuery('body').waitForImages(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: You need to enable the `waitForAll` option for the plugin to consider background images.

Answer (score 1):

did you try with JQuery? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(pageLoaded)
</script>
```

Comment: I think you want `$(document).load(pageLoaded);` http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. This attaches a function to the event that occurs when images and other elements on the page have loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Or listen for DOM ready [without jQuery](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml)