# How to make something load first before another in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with text in it and a background image. When I load the page the text always appear 1st(assume i have low speed internet connection). How can i make the background image load before text? Can You please give me solution in both jquery and javascript

Comment: Can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: I don't really understand I was going to suggest chucking java at the bottom

Comment: For those answers suggesting the jQuery Load event, be sure to see the "caveats" section in the API: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. As such, I'd probably suggest user1026361's answer, if you are ok w/ preloading the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the text in the [onload event handler](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) for the image.

Note:  If you want to keep using a `div` tag with a background image rather than an `img` tag, you'll have to add the text during the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) event (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538472/508537) for the details).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your div looks like this:

```
<div id="Derp" style="CSS-for-background-image-here">Magical ponies!</div>
```

I would try removing the text completely and then add this kind of jquery call:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Derp').load(function() {
            $('#Derp').text("Magical ponies!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `$('#Derp').load(...)` is the key here. [See the docs for load().](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) It has an example of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

you could populate the content onload.

Start with this:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then, in jquery, do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    mybg= new Image(); 
    mybg.onload=function(){
      $('#content').html('YOURTEXTHERE');
    }
    mybg.src = "PATH/TO/IMG";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

your simple answer is `.load` you can do when your window gets loaded fully and then text appears:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('p').fadeIn(800);
    });​
});
```

what this is doing is `fading in the p tag with text` when whole `window gets loaded`.

you can find a demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/a5P8b/**