# Prioritise a div or image to load first

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading

Here's some example code, I would like to prioritise "div1" to load before anything else does.

```
<HTML>
<body>
<div id="div1">This div will load first please</div>
<img src="/" title="Other large images">
<img src="/" title="Other large images">
<img src="/" title="Other large images">
<img src="/" title="Other large images">
<img src="/" title="Other large images">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It already will, what is the issue you are having?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make something load first before another in javascript and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918170/how-to-make-something-load-first-before-another-in-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: @DeniJ. From the title, it certainly looks promising!

Comment: @rdmptn Why would it be prioritised?

Comment: Because it's the first element from the html the browser will parse and render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just via `HTML` you cannot prioritize what will load first on your web page.

The page loads from the **Top to Down** approach, which first `<HEAD>`  and its content, then `<BODY>` and its content.

If you like to render a page according to your need you need to use JavaScript.

Below sample code below does the same.

```js
window.onload = function(){
   
   const div1 = `<div id="div1">This div will load first please</div>`;
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log("DIV1 load after 3 second");
     document.getElementById("the-div-1").innerHTML = div1;
   }, 3000); 
   
   const imgs = `
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" title="Other large images">
      <br />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300.jpg" title="Other large images">
      <br />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" title="Other large images">
      <br />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300.jpg" title="Other large images">
      <br />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/200/300.jpg" title="Other large images">
      <br />
   `;

  setTimeout(() => {
     console.log("Images load after 6 second");
     document.getElementById("image-div").innerHTML = imgs;
   }, 6000); 
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <span>Anything in HTML file will load from top-down apporach.</span>
  </div>
  
  <div id="the-div-1"></div>
  
  <div id="image-div"></div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.onload`
[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

```html
<div id="a"><!--other stuff--></div>
<div onload="loadOtherContent()">IMPORTANT DIV</div>
<div id="b"><!--other stuff--></div>
<script>
const loadOtherContent = () => {
    //load those other stuff
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "...";
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "...";
    //...
}
</script>
```