# javascript animations not happening in right order (some computers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Okay firstly, excuse me I'm new to js and learning it as I go. Basically I have a site I'm building here: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/

Animation should go like this: page loads, ellement (.detroit) slides in from left, then element (.windsor) slides in from right, then element (.site-header-home & #dashboard) slide in from top.

It looks fine most of the time, but I've noticed that if the internet connection is weak, then the either the 2nd or 3rd animation initiates first instead of going sequentially.

Here's the (sloppy) js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.site-header-home').delay(2500).slideDown(200);

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#dashboard").delay(200).animate({
        right: "-270px"
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false
    });
}, 2500);

$('.open').bind('click',function(){ 
    $('#dashboard').stop().animate(
    {
        right: $(this).hasClass('close') ? '-270px' : '0'
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
});


setTimeout(function() {
    $(".detroit").delay(500).animate({
        left: "0"
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false
    });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".windsor").delay(500).animate({
        right: "0"
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false
    });
}, 2000);
});
```

If anyone can offer advice on how I can ensure that these animations will happen in the right order I would appreciate it!

thanks!

Comment: What browsers have this problem?

Comment: Take a look at [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: @Dude I've only checked in ff so far, but it seems to be more of an issue with internet signal strength then the browser. If the page takes too long to load, things happen out of order.

Comment: Well, maybe other browsers get it right. Maybe they don't, which is kind of a problem. I recommend http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: @kei from what I understand that seems to be useful if you're adding multiple animations to one element. I have 1 animation for 4 elements, but they need to happen sequentially.

Comment: @Dude but that still won't help things from loading differently on 1 browser right? I need it to operate the same way every time the page loads, regardless of signal strength or browser.

Comment: In this case, use the on `complete` function in [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to chain them all together.

Comment: @kei so it looks like that will work, but I don't think I'm using it correctly. What I've done is added the 2nd animation in after / inside the 1st one, but now only the first one loads. eg.           setTimeout(function() {
    $(".detroit").delay(500).animate({
        left: "0"
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false
     });
 }, 1000, function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
     $(".windsor").delay(500).animate({
         right: "0"
     }, {
         duration: 200,
         queue: false
      });
  }, 2000);
 });

Comment: Well, different browsers may have different problems. I'm not saying it will help you, I'm just saying you should pay attention to different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so upon doing more digging I came across this answer from @Matchu to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded). This is what I needed to make it work.

Basically it needs to wrapped in the `window.onload` function as the `$(document).ready` function was specifically made so that functions would load once the DOM was ready, but not necessarily before images were loaded.

I've included an edited example of the code from my question which includes much cleaner code, provided by @kei who kindly helped with this as well.

```
window.onload = function () { 

    $('.open').bind('click',function(){ 
            $('#dashboard').stop().animate({
            right: $(this).hasClass('menu-close') ? '-480px' : '0'
            });
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-close');
    }); 

    $(".detroit").delay(500).animate({
            left: 0
    }, 200,

    function () {
            $(".windsor").delay(500).animate({
            right: 0
        }, 200,

    function () {
        $(".site-header-home").delay(200).slideDown(200,

        function () {
                $("#dashboard").animate({
                right: "-480px"
            }, 200);    
        });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `complete` properly. You do not need `setTimeout` for this.

Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zmy4E/) to get you started.

```
$("#div1")
    .animate({
    left: 0
}, 1000,
function () {
    $("#div2").animate({
        right: 0
    }, 1000,
    function () {
        $("#div3").animate({
            top: 0
        }, 1000)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kei this helped a lot in my understanding of how these functions get strung together and helps with my understanding of js in general. It doesn't seem to fix the problem for me, though. If the images are saved in my cache, everything happens perfectly, if I clear my cache though, I get varied results. Either none of the functions load, they all load at the same time, or again, they load out of order.