# Facebook like box slows down website

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance

I've added a Facebook Like Box to a website and it's really slowing down the page. Loading the page is finished in between 3 seconds and up to a minute or even more. I'm already loading the Facebook JavaScript asynchronous but without much improved results.

I really have no clue why it's slowing the website that much and with so many variable loading times. Have been adding multiple Facebook Like boxes to different sites and they all load fast (enough) without slowing down the general loading time that much.

What could be wrong here that causes this slow loading times? The website keep connecting and connecting and eventually showing the Facebook Like box.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.async=true; js.src =   "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxAppIDcodeXX";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Any help or ideas are very much welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say anything about the load time of your page just from the code you pasted; but you can try to load the facebook like button when everything else is loaded. See this post:

[Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: That's already happening. The content of the website is fully loaded in like 2 or seconds but after that it keeps connecting and connecting and eventually showing the Facebook Like box on the page.

Comment: Is it because you use facebook.net?

Change it to:
"//connect.facebook.com/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxAppIDcodeXX";