# How to change html content, when the page has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>TestPage</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="test">Sample text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this JS file

```
window.addEventListener("load", MyFunction());
function MyFunction(){
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "it worked";
}
```

and ofcourse this doesn't work (the text isn't changed), since it loads the script before it actually loads the `<p id="test"></p>` element (I think). It may seem strange, but I want to change the content of some elements, after everything has loaded. I have searched, but to no avail. I'm missing something obvious here probably, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You are immediately executing `MyFunction`, replace `MyFunction()` with `MyFunction`

Comment: also you shouldn't use a captial letter in My, because these are usually only used for classes (or javascript's weird prototype system)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling the function in the setup for your "load" event.

Did you mean:

```
window.addEventListener("load", MyFunction);
```

??

Comment: This is the correct answer, remove the brackets in your event hander

Comment: Oh my, that's it. My apologies for missing it! Thank you! (I can only accept your answer in a couple of minutes though, will do!)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    MyFunction() 
}

function MyFunction(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "it worked";
}
```

Source: [Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Answer (score -1):

Simply add this to your body tag :

```
<body onload=myFunction()>

function myFunction(){
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "it worked";
}
```