# Javascript counter increment not working

Tags: javascript

I have a counter on my html page and im trying to use a button to increment the counter by 1 when using the + button, and decrease the counter by 1 when using the - button, with a maximum of 10 counts (0 minimum). Problem is the javascript doesnt seem to work at all. When I click the buttons, nothing happens.
I have google hosting jquery in my header.
I've tried this on js fiddle and it works but not on my page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**html (these are inside a div)**

```
   <button onclick="countDown();">-</button>
            <span id="counter">0</span>
            <button onclick="countUp();">+</button>
```

**Javacript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var minVal = 0, maxVal = 10, clicks = 0,
 display = document.getElementById("counter");

    function countUp() {
        clicks = Math.min(maxVal, clicks + 1);
        display.innerHTML = clicks;
    }

    function countDown() {
        clicks = Math.max(minVal, clicks - 1);
        display.innerHTML = clicks;
       }
</script>
```

Edit: the script is in my header after the jquery script

Comment: Have you taken a look at the console? Any error messages there?

Comment: Aren't you trying to `getElementById` before the element exists? You stated jQuery, have you tried to put that piece of code inside a `$(document).ready()` block?

Comment: You have this script in the head, so that means when the page loads, the element (`#counter`) isn't there yet. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1033398/940217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that `display` is not set, because the document has not loaded yet, and therefore `document.getElementById("counter")` would not return an element (the `#counter` element does not exist yet). Instead of putting the script in the header, try putting it after the `#counter` span.

You can check to see if this is true by opening the console. If there is an error message, something along the lines of `Error: trying to set property "innerHTML" of undefined`, that would be the problem.

[Here is a working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/w1pr6hxf/)

---

And this isn't just a question-specific tip— you almost always want to have your JavaScript load *after* the DOM (the HTML) loads. So either enclose all your script in a `window.onload` or `$(document).ready()` (jQuery) event handler, or put the script at the end of the `<body>` as was this case.

---

Per your request in the comments, if you want to use an external script, do the same thing. Put it an external file and include it with a `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>` at the end of the body, and it should do just the same.

Comment: It worked!! I put the script at the end of the page, just before the </body>

Comment: Question though, if I expand on this js, which I might need to, I should probably put it in an external js file. If I do this, will I have the same problem of it not getting the counter?

Comment: @user2903379 I'll explain that in my answer in a sec. There you go.

Comment: @Johnathan Lam Thank you so much!