# How to wait for complete page load (including images etc.)

Tags: dojo

I want to show a "Please wait while the page is loading..." message while my page is loading. The page contains a lot of small images which take some time to load. So I don't want to hide the message before these are loaded as well.

I tried to use `dojo/domReady!` and `dojo/ready`, but they fire before the images are loaded and thus the page still looks incomplete when I hide the message at this point.

The following code works, but doesn't seem to be the dojo way:

```
window.onload = hideLoadingMessage();
```

Registering to `window.onload` with `on` doesn't work at all:

```
require([ 'dojo/_base/window', 'dojo/on' ], function(win, on) {
  on(win, 'onload', hideLoadingMessage);
});
```

How should I wait for the page to be completely loaded including all the images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: @brclz this is partly a duplicate as here Jan Schatz was asking for a dojo way of doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect to the window `load` event, you should not use `dojo/_base/window`.

Instead just use plain `window` object. Also use `load` as event name (and not `onload`).
Using directly `window` object avoid loading a module that you don't need.

See the below snippets with both solutions (`window` object and `dojo/_base/_window` module):

```js
require(['dojo/_base/window', 'dojo/on'], function(baseWin, on) {
  on(window, 'load', function() {
    alert('loaded - using global window object!');
  });
  
  on(baseWin.global, 'load', function() {
    alert('loaded - using dojo window module!');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you think the global _window_ variable is better than _dojo/_base/window_'s _global_ variable? Of course I forgot the _.global_ above.

Comment: Unless you use managed context (and dealing with frames) `dojo/_base/window::global` is just an alias to `window` object. Using directly `window` object avoid loading a module that you don't need