# Put Script into JavaScript File

Tags: javascript

So I have a script like this inside my html:

```
<script> 
    var slider = new Slider("#pics", {
        tooltip: 'always'
    });
</script>
```

I was to put this script inside a JavaScript file, so am assuming I am going to turn it into a `function`

Like this:

```
function change_pics(){
var slider = new Slider("#pics", {
        tooltip: 'always'
    });
}
```

is this correct way ?

Comment: You should not to forget include this js file into page. It can be function or variable, depends where you want to use it

Comment: You don't need to turn that into a function. But, don't forget to add your js file in the html page

Comment: I'd recommend to follow this pattern. http://imrealashu.in/code/javascript/how-to-write-javascript-library/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script:

```
var slider = new Slider("#pics", {
    tooltip: 'always'
});
```

into a JS file, lets say "slider.js". Then you should import that JS file into your HTML file :

```
`<script src="PATH_TO_YOUR_JS_FILE"></script>`
```

You don't have to turn it into a function.

Comment: I use the script in a input like this:

`<input id="ex8" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>`

This will not work, because I think I need an `onclick` or another property to trigger, no ?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please be more specific? If you have to attach an onclick event to your button, you can also do this directly into a js file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to compartmentalize as you mention, but don't absolutely have to.  If you pop just what you have between the `<script>` tags into change.js without the function declaration, you can literally just put this in your HTML:

```
<script src="change.js"></script>
```

...and it will behave like you copy/pasted the contents wherever you put the tags.

Do put the explicit `</script>` in there, because `<script ... />` works only in XHTML files.

Comment: I use the script in a input like this: `<input id="ex8" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>` This will not work, because I think I need an `onclick` or another property to trigger, no ?

Comment: I think you're using this? http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/. If so, you will need to pull in their css and JavaScript sources first (inside <head> somewhere is traditional).  Then if you put your own <script> somewhere handy (bottom of file is traditional), it will run on doc load.  Using jQuery is a bit better as it will avoid races (or use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1033448/6664886).  In any case, nothing special needed to activate--just run your code as written and you should be good.