# Make a simple private variable global - accessing body elements

Tags: javascript

A beginner question indeed but can't find anywhere on stackoverflow that actually solves this, so any help would be really appreciated. I just want to define a private variable and then return it to the global scope.

In this example, I can access x in the JS console after refreshing the page - but the script runs before the body loads (source at end of head tag) and I cannot create elements that relate to the body content since they haven't loaded yet:

```
var x = 5;

window.onload = function() {
    var y = 10;
}
```

I cannot access variable y, presumably because it's a private variable that's not available on the global scope (am I actually correct here?). Using return fails. I just want to be able to create variables from the body, but I can't because the script hasn't loaded in time.

How can this be achieved? I actually can't solve this presumably simple problem. Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a function when page has fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/how-to-execute-a-function-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: Depending on how you're trying to access y your assumption that you can't access it because it's private may not be the whole truth... If you try to console.log(y) outside of a window.onload function it will execute before y is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously can't access y outside of a window.onload function like this, since the window hasn't loaded by the time you check what y is.

```js
var x = 5;

window.onload = function() {
    var y = 10;
}

console.log(y)
```

Assuming you don't mean that and you're just using onload as an example of a function, you can use `window.y` as a substitute for `var y` and it will be global on the window, so you can use it outside of the function.

```js
var x = 5;

function define_y() {
  window.y = 10;
}

window.onload = function() {
  define_y();
  console.log(y);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way that I use when I need a variable in my console, is assigning them to `window` like this:

```
window.y = y;
```

Then in your console, `y` as well as `window.y` will be that variable :)

Answer (score 2):

Declare `y` in the global scope and initialize it in the onload function.

```
var x = 5;
var y;
window.onload = function() {
    y = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global namespace and add properties later to it.

```
var namespace = Object.create(null); // empty object without prototypes

window.onload = function() {
    namespace.y = 10;
}
```