# How to return a value with EvaluateScriptAsync() only once the DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

I have asked a question not too long ago on how to wait for a script to be executed by cefSharp before continuing my main program and I was advised to use `await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(...)` this works fine when I am not using any EventHandler.
But say that I want to wait for the Dom to be loaded before executing my script I would use the following event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

What I want to do now is return true once the Dom is loaded (and return nothing before).This would theoretically allow my program to wait till the dom is loaded before the execution continues. So what I tried to do was the following :

```
    await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync( "
    function returnTrue() {
    return true;
    }

    function waitForDom(callback) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      console.log('hi');  
      callback();
    });

    waitForDom(returnTrue);
    "};

console.WriteLine("outside");
```

The expected output would be :

```
hi
outside
```

but what I get is :

```
outside
hi
```

This implies that my main program doesn't wait for the Dom to be loaded before continuing.

Why does this not work ?

Comment: Just evaluate your script in LoadingStateChange event in c# and the DOM should be ready see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript for an example.

Comment: @amaitland really helpful answer like always, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

or if javascript only

```
window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!") }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033448/5517161

Comment: Window on load doesn't work in my case since I only want the Dom to be loaded and not all the images etc.

Comment: and event if i try await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!"); return true; }"); the program doesnt seem to wait for the page to be loaded

Comment: Not sure how to use await/async with an event listener. Could you try to explain it ?