# Trying to set the src attribute of a video using JavaScript, getting TypeError: videofile is null

Tags: javascript, html, null

I have a video and some JavaScript code. The code says

```js
var videoIDRAW = getUrlVars()["watch"];
var videoID = videoIDRAW.toString();
var videoIDFILE = videoID.concat(".mp4");
var videofile = document.getElementById("vid");

videofile.setAttribute("src", videofile)
```

videofile is

```html
<video width="912" height="513" controls >
<source id="vid" src="" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

why do i get the TypeError: videofile is null?

EDIT: modified `videofile.setAttribute("src", videofile.toString())`, same error

Comment: Your code seems to be semantic incorrect. You are trying to add the source id="vid" as src for itself. You have to generate a link for some kind and then add it to the source element.

Comment: Aaron what do you mean by that

Comment: You get the DOM element <source id="vid"> and use the function toString on it which makes no sense at all. I post a working version.

Comment: Seblor tried that, nothing new apparently

Comment: @lambdaguy101 Just make sure you are loading your script *after* the body has loaded, otherwise calling `document.getElementById` will return null (because the elements are not yet created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString()` is not a magical tool. It should have been called by default anyway I think.

As Aaros pointed out, the issue lies in what your algorithm tries to do. You are trying to set a DOM element as the value of *one of its own attributes*. The src attribute of a video needs to be the video's URL (or blob, but that's more complicated).

Didn't you mean this ?

```
videofile.setAttribute("src", videoIDFILE); // Or videofile.src = videoIDFILE
```

**Edit:** Don't forget to execute your script *after* the body. Either by moving the `script` tag to the bottom of the body (but still inside), or you can use a listener like you can find there : [How to execute a function when page has fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/how-to-execute-a-function-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: I can't edit my post but here's the code that I modified

Comment: var videoIDRAW = getUrlVars()["watch"];
var videoID = videoIDRAW.toString();
var videoIDFILE = videoID.concat(".mp4");
var videofile = document.getElementById("vid");

videofile.setAttribute("src", videoIDFILE)

Comment: it does the exact same thing

Comment: Have you looked at my new comment or edit ? Also you should be able to edit your question.