# On loading everything breaks for a sec CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've just finished my website and I've discovered that when my website loads on mobile it shows me the "display text" format plus the responsive menu flashes(opens) for a sec and then the site fully loads.

- **CSS file linked in the head**
- **JS files at the bottom**
- **It shows me div's set to `display: none; in CSS`  on mobile for sec**

I've tried to capture a screenshot:
[image]

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong hours now without success.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a cache plugin? The issue is wordpress related, not just css.

Comment: Is the `display: none;` set in the JavaScript? If so, it may be displaying before the JS has a chance to parse.

Comment: @FedericaVenuto Thanks for the reply I don't use a cache plugin. What you see is because I'm logged in. Here is without: [link](https://i.imgur.com/0rzA6K4.png)

Comment: @TylerSmith Thanks for the reply. No `display: none; ` is set in the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and removing code piece by piece, I've found a function that disables `wp_emojicons` that for some reason it makes the CSS to load late.

```
function disable_wp_emojicons() {

/* all actions related to emojis */
  remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
  remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
  remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
  remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
  remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
  remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );

/* filter to remove TinyMCE emojis */
  add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojicons_tinymce' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [Flash Of Unstyled Content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). Your Javascript takes more time to load than your CSS and your page is displayed before the Javascript has the time to hide stuff.

- You could either put the Javascript in the `<head>`.
- Use default styling in the CSS that would later be override by Javascript. As stated by @TylerSmith in the comments, if you want your panel to be hidden in the first place, use `display: none` in the CSS.
- Show a loading screen until the `load` event of the `window` is [triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/how-to-execute-a-function-when-page-has-fully-loaded).

Comment: I also think that this is the problem. I just want to note a loader screen would be a possible solution here.

Comment: I dont think is a JS problem as the issue also occurs when js files are not embedded. I'm using `display: none` in the CSS file.

Comment: How is your CSS linked? @trunks It could be that your stylesheet being a little bit, takes a little while to load letting the browser display elements with their default styles.